# Should I embed a command in a conditional or test its return code?

Tags: bash, exit, patterns

It's a simple question of best pratices: Which should I use?

Option 1

```sh
ping -c1 "$host"

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
   command
else
   command
fi
```

Option 2

```sh
if ping -c1 "$host" ; then
   command
else
   command
fi
```

I know this is a simple command, but if it grows big, the difference might be significant.

Answer (score 5):

It's a matter of preference, but the second form may be safer if you intend to add a `set -e`: this form will still work as expected, while with the first form, the script will end immediately if `ping` fails (returns with a non-zero exit status).

Note: the operator is `-eq`, not `eq`.

Comment: Just typo the operator. But thx, I prefer the second one :D

Answer (score 3):

Option 2 is only an option when you only care about the difference between success and failure. If you need to differentiate between different non-zero exit statuses, then option 1 is necessary.

```
some-command arg1 arg2
exit_status=$?
if [[ $exit_status -eq 0 ]]; then
   # ...
elif [[ $exit_status -eq 1 ]]; then
   # ...
elif [[ $exit status -eq 42 ]]; then
   # ...
else
   # ...
fi
```

(You need to save `$?` as `exit_status` because `$?` will be reset by the first `[[ ... ]]` command; if it fails, the first `elif` wouldn't test the same value for `$?` again.)

Well, not quite *necessary*. A third option is to use a `case` statement, which can eliminate the need for saving `$?` if you don't need to refer to its value again.

```
some-command arg1 arg2
case $? in
   0) # ...
   ;;
   1) # ...
   ;;
   42) # ...
   ;;
   *) # ...
   ;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Bash idiom which may seem unreadable but is quite common in practice.

```
ping -c1 "$host" && command_success || command_failure
```

Comment: Yeah, know that. Can use the || also!